# Is it possible to override a core function instead of just altering it?

Tags: 8, views

I would like to add a feature to the core string contextual filter, implemented in core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/argument/StringArgument.php.

If I use `hook_views_query_alter()`, I would have to undo everything the core function did first, then roll out my changes.

Is there a way to just completely override the core function instead of only altering the results?

The contextual range filter accomplishes this by presenting the site admin with a configuration page to select which instances of an existing filter should be replaced by the new object. I could follow this route, but I would prefer to update all cases site-wide.

Comment: as you can see the StringArgument is a plugin, so you can simply alter the plugin registry and point to your own class.

Comment: Would this be a global change or have to be done for each view after it is created? Ideally I would like to extend the core StringArgument and just change the couple methods that need to be changed, and use it instead of the core Plugin.

Comment: This depends, you have to look which plugin classes are the ones really used by Views. For example the node module extends `NumericArgument` and `StringArgument` to `Nid` and `Type`. So if you want to override contextual filters for content globally, you have to override these plugins and replace them in hook_views_data_alter().

Comment: So if i want this new version of the StringArgument to be used site-wide and I name it `@ViewsArgument("string_operator")`,  I imagine I would have to have an install script run hook_views_data_alter to do something like `$current = $data[$table_name][$field_name]['argument']['id']; if ($current == 'string') $data[$table_name][$field_name]['argument']['id'] = 'string_operator';`. Then how do I let drupal know that my new argument is the default to use for all future string fields?

Comment: Alternatively, should I name my plugin 'string' and use some hook to change whatever translates `Drupal\views\Plugin\views\argument\StringArgument.php = @ViewsArgument("string")` to `Drupal\views\Plugin\views\argument\StringArgument.php = @ViewsArgument("string_old")`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would make an inheritance from this core plugin, extend it in my own class (classes), and change in the views to use my custom plugin.

Comment: I have reverted the core StringArgument back to the original version, created a module, moved my file here, and made it extend StringArgument. I see two routes forward. I can either name it @ViewsArgument("string"), and somehow tell drupal to ignore the core StringArgument, or I can name it @ViewsArgument("string_operator") and somehow tell Drupal that all existing and future fields of type string need to use the string_operator plugin. Any suggestions on which to do and how? As a test, I renamed the core file to "string_old" and my new one to "string" and it works.

Comment: Am sorry I don't have that much knowledge about views and this argument stuff. So I won't able to help you with that.

The test COULD be a working solution, if you for example rename the core file with a patch (and put the patch into the composer.json). 
But definitely a dirty solution.